# Getting a 412 (Precondition Failed) on a social network, why?

Tags: javascript, html, get

GET https://******.co/search?page=2 412 (Precondition Failed) application-4d80cd2e47625f2cae4003e045f8f47a.js:3Y.cors.t.crossDomain.send application-4d80cd2e47625f2cae4003e045f8f47a.js:3Z.extend.ajax application-4d80cd2e47625f2cae4003e045f8f47a.js:3xyz.InfiniteScrollService.r.wasScrolled application-4d80cd2e47625f2cae4003e045f8f47a.js:8(anonymous function) application-4d80cd2e47625f2cae4003e045f8f47a.js:8o

This occurs when I try to see my friends list on a social networking site.
Why is it happening?

The list of friends does not appear.
I tried to scroll down the page by using this statement :

```
myVar = setInterval(function () {
    $(".panel").scrollTop($(".panel")[0].scrollHeight)
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: We are not fortune tellers, we can't help you without any detail...

Comment: @MarcoBonelli edited the post, is that better.

Comment: Your script has nothing to do with that error.. if you are getting a 412 you're probably doing an XHR or something, but not a scroll to bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After googling for about 3 seconds:

> This error seldom occurs in most Web traffic, particularly when the client system is a Web browser. The problem can only be resolved by examining what your client system is trying to do then discussing with your ISP why the Web server fails the 'Precondition' specification sent by the client system.

My best guess: Call your ISP, or contact the owners of the social network you're doing this on.

**Edit:**

After looking at your code, what you're trying does not involve any ajax or http requests. Either the error is occuring somewhere else in your code or on the server end.